# memory layout of two C++ classes sharing the same members

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class `X` such that all its non-static members are PODs, and a class `Y` that has the same members in the same order as `X`, and is also POD itself. Is it legal to `reinterpret_cast` an instance of `Y` to `X`? If it's not, will it work in practice across platforms?

To give you a bit of background, my class `X` has itself as static members for convenience (i.e. `class X { ... public: static const X& a; static const X& b; }`, and I want to remove static initializers without changing the API. My plan was to create global static objects of `Y` type and `reinterpret_cast` them to `X` -- since all members are POD, I don't need constructor to be run.

Comment: Why not have a base class? Saves on the mystery in life

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` will probably work in practice. Putting the two into a union, you're explicitly allowed to refer to the `common initial sequence` of fields, which (in this case) would be all the fields.

Comment: @EdHeal "Without changing the API"

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Subject to the usual constraints. E.g. if you have `void f(X*, Y*)`, then don't make a union and call `f(&u.x, &u.y)` etc.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - does `class Base { protected: int x,y,z;};` followed by `class D : public Base` and `class E : public Base` change the interface for `D` and `E`?

Comment: It should work. Though its Undefined Behaviour by the standard... Doing it is like sitting on a keg of gunpowder... "Think of the day someone tries to refactor your code" ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -  Pray tell - In what way? D has is own bunch of methods that can differ from E. Anything with access to D or E cannot access anything in Base

Comment: @EdHeal: Adding a base makes it non-POD which changes the binary interface, doesn't it? I haven't checked just guessing from memory

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the layout of the members are exactly the same and you are not introducing any inheritance you can "safely" `reinterpret_cast`. I put "safely" in quotes for a reason, doing this seems simply a bad idea, you say you want to

> ...remove static initializers without changing the API. My plan was to create global static objects...

Why would you do this? Keeping a set of static variables in a class has only one drawback, you have to type the name of the class whenever you use it.  *Also adding the `static` keyword to a global variable doesn't behave the same as in a class declaration.* `static` when appended to a global variable  means that the compiler will only use it in the scope of the translation unit. This means that you could potentially have multiple globals with the same name in separate files. Again this is only adding to the complexity, though you did not specify why you want to do this exactly, i can safely say that what you are trying to accomplish should be and could be solved in a much more scope-oriented fashion.

Comment: Initializers for statics are in the hot path to main(),  are not parallelized, and lead to hard-to-find bugs related to initialization order. The project I'm working on has a strict policy against them.